# Overriding default automatic SVN properties with svn:auto-props

Tags: svn, svn-propset

Is it possible to somehow override default algorithm for assigning SVN properties using the `svn:auto-props`? (Obviously only for those that do use `svn:auto-props`...)

In particular how do I assure that `svn:executable` *is not set* based on corresponding permission flag? Since default automatic properties assignment will look at the executable permission flag and if it is set it will assign `svn:executable`. While I would like to automatically assign this flag only to files explicitly listed in `svn:executable`. (Obviously user will still be able to set the property manually skipping any default algorithm.)

Comment: Do you ask about `svn:auto-props` versioned property (requires SVN 1.8+ client) or about similar client runtime configuration section [auto-props]?

Comment: I meant versioned property. That is why I named it `svn:auto-props` not `[auto-props]` ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, [`svn:auto-props`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.html#svn.advanced.props.auto) in SVN 1.8 does not cover such case (at least the way how I understood your case, i.e. some elaboration on your question would make it clearer). In can only set a property based on the specified pattern, it can't deny setting a property on some specific working copy items.

In other words, if you specify a pattern, those items in your WC that match the pattern will definitely get `svn:executable` applied.

Comment: Even if I would include a match for everything (`*`) that would not list `svn:executable` it would still be set for files with corresponging permissions flag? (Disregarding that such a match causes other issues.)

Comment: It will be set on ALL file, i.e. it will propagate downlevel on items matching `*` pattern. In case of `*` on all files.

Comment: But what will be set? If I will make something like: `* = svn:mime-type=text/plain` then every single file will get such `svn:mime-type` property (assuming clients will honor `svn:auto-props`!). But will also every file not have `svn:executable` set automatically? Or will still files with executable bit permission have that property set?